Excel return value between multiple sheets
I have an excel sheet where the first one is a master sheet of organizations within the US. I want to make additional sheets that have the organizations within each specific state as well, but want to make it so that I only have to edit the master sheet, and then the subsequent sheets would update automatically.
Is there a function that would help me on this?

What is your source of the data?

The source would be Column A of Sheet 1 (Master Sheet). There's content in the other columns as well, and I was hoping for the function to pull in the rows of data in Sheet 1 onto sheet 2 if the row in column A of sheet 1 has a certain US state

Could you edit your question and include some sample data please so it's clear how the data is set out.  Also - what version of Excel?   You've tagged both 2010 and 2007.

seems like a filter on the state column (you do have that don't you) on the master sheet would suffice? What are you exactly trying to do that you need separate sheets?

Is there a function to help you do what? Your description is very poor. Can you explain with examples/data?
